# git-http-backend and LDAP authentication, push error: requested URL returned error: 401 Authorization Required

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap, authentication, git

My setup

- OS: debian
- git: v 1.7.10
- apache (with suexec mode enabled) configuration with git-http-backend and LDAP authorization to git repos which works for clone operations, but not working for push and that's the problem. I use HTTPS as communication protocol to my git server.

Here's my config:

**VirtualHost config:**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

    DocumentRoot /git/myrepos

    <Directory "/git/myrepos">
    Allow from All
    Options +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

ScriptAlias /git /git/myrepos/bin/suexec-wrapper.sh
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/git.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/git.key

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
```

**/git/myrepos/bin/suexec-wrapper.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH_INFO=$SCRIPT_URL
GIT_PROJECT_ROOT=/git/myrepos
REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
export GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL=true
/usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend
```

Cloning repos works as it should (eg. `git clone https://192.168.0.1/repo1.git`). It accept credentials for ldap user and clone the repo.

And when pushing repo (eg. `git push origin master`), it ask for credentials, accept them and then throws error:

```
error: Cannot access URL https://192.168.0.1/repo1.git/, return code 22
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

When running push in verbose mode (`GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push origin master`), it ask for credentials, accept them and (tail of output):

```
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x1cdd270; (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x1cdd270; (connection #0)
* STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x1cdd270; (connection #0)
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* The requested URL returned error: 401
* Closing connection #0
* Expire cleared
error: Cannot access URL https://192.168.0.1/repo1.git/, return code 22
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

- Am I configuring apache git-http-backend (with wrap script?) properly?
- And what can cause the problem with push operation?
- How to debug it more detailed way?

Any suggestions very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries I've found the solution. The problem was in incorrect VirtualHost configuration for git-http-backend.

Here's my working config:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

        DocumentRoot /git/myrepos

        SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /git/myrepos
        SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
        ScriptAlias /myrepos/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend
        AliasMatch ^/myrepos/(.*/objects/[0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38})$ /git/myrepos/$1
        AliasMatch ^/repos/(.*/objects/pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}.(pack|idx))$ /git/myrepos/$1

        ScriptAliasMatch "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | info/refs | objects/(info/[^/]+ | [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/$1

        <Directory "/usr/lib/git-core/">
        Options +ExecCGI
        Allow From All
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/git.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/git.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown


<Location /repo1.git>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from all
AuthName "GIT Authentication"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
AuthLDAPBindDN domain\user
AuthLDAPBindPassword passwd
AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldap.server:389/ou=git,DC=domain?sAMAccountName
Require ldap-group cn=git_repo1,ou=git,dc=domain
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Now all git operations works properly with git-http-backend via https with ldap authorization :)

Maybe it will be useful for someone.